# CSS flexbox image centering

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have a variable set of images I'm displaying in a flexbox, and am trying to make sure the images vertically and horizontally align to their parent div. I've tried the usual vertical-align, text-align, max-width: 100%;, and margin: 0 auto;. Any good cross browser solutions to my dilemma that won't lead to warped/left-aligned images?

Here's the CSS (in it's current borky form, I've also tried the other aforementioned centering CSS):

```
.collage{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    display: -webkit-box;     
    display: -moz-box; 
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: inline-flex;   
    flex-direction: column;
}

.collage div{
    display: -webkit-box; 
    display: -moz-box;     
    display: -ms-flexbox;  
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: inline-flex;  
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.collage img{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hSb93/3/

Comment: Added the CSS, the code is simply some php that takes a list of images and puts it into a square grid of divs inside the .collage div.

Comment: what is your problem is it vertical image centering

Comment: Mostly horizontal, everything is currently left-aligning or just stretching whilst not maintaining aspect ratio when I try my usual 100% center-align tricks

Comment: ok it hard to understand the problem here could you create a fiddle

Comment: Updated JSFiddle link to better exemplify the issue, images are currently stretched and left aligned.

Comment: have you tried floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `margin: auto;` to `.collage img` it solves it.

But flexbox is not supported by all browsers.

If you want it to be fully cross-browser you can put a span before the image and put this CSS in it:

CSS

```
 .collage div{
   text-align: center;
 }

span{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <img>
</div>
```